# What UNIX commands support coloured output?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, colors, ls-colors

I enjoy using UNIX/bash commands that support coloured output.  Consequently, I have a few aliases defined which automatically enable coloured output of the commands that I know support this option.  However, I'm sure there are hundreds of commands out there that support coloured output - I'd like to know what they are.

The ones in my `~/.bash_aliases` file are:

```
ls --color=auto
grep --color
phpunit --ansi
```

What else is there?  Is there a list somewhere of all commands that support coloured output?  Or better still, some command for grepping my local man pages and plucking out the appropriate command names.

Comment: Strictly speaking, these are GNU programs (AFIAK). And as we all know: GNU's Not Unix!

Comment: I guess you mean more than two colours? :-)

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you try:

```
man -K color
```

That should search for the word color in all your man pages (content, not just headings).

It asks, for each man page, whether you want to open and view the page:

```
$ man -K color
/usr/share/man/mann/Widget.n.gz? [ynq] y
/usr/share/man/mann/usual.n.gz? [ynq] y
/usr/share/man/mann/Toplevel.n.gz? [ynq] n
/usr/share/man/mann/itk.n.gz? [ynq] n
/usr/share/man/mann/Archetype.n.gz? [ynq] n
/usr/share/man/man8/squid.8.gz? [ynq] n
/usr/share/man/man7/Xprint.7.gz? [ynq]
/usr/share/man/man7/X.7.gz? [ynq]
/usr/share/man/man7/urxvt.7.gz? [ynq]
/usr/share/man/man7/term.7.gz? [ynq] q

$
```

Inside each individual man page, you can use your normal search method (e.g., `/color<ENTER>`) for finding the text. When done with a man page, just exit and it will continue searching.

Comment: My system uses a lower-case k. But I usually use apropos.

Comment: Dennis, I think that the lowercase k just searches the headings, not the full text.

Answer (score 8):

A quick bit of google search also reveals [`grc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/grc.1.html) and [`grcat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/grcat.1.html), which can be used to colorise any arbitrary text or command. Not sure how well they work though. I'm certainly going to try them out now that I've found them.

Ah, here we go. `grc` uses the `/etc/grc.conf` file to colorise a given command based on which regexp it matches. A quick grep of my (Ubuntu 8.10) `/etc/grc.conf` reveals it currently has support for:

```
[~]$ less /etc/grc.conf | grep '^#'
# anything to do with irc
# log file
# ping command
# traceroute command
# gcc command
# make command
# netstat command
# diff command
# last command
# ldap tools
# cvs command
```

But I'm sure you could add your own for other programs you are interested in.

To use `grc`, simply put it before the command you want to colorise (lets say `diff`):

```
grc diff foo.txt bar.txt
```

And you could certainly `alias diff='grc diff'` to make `diff` colorised by default.

Comment: `grc` had a helper script: `grcat`. Here is an example of colouring all capital letters in red. Step 1: Set up the config file: `printf "regexp=[A-Z]\ncolours=red\n" > ~/.grc/red-caps`  Step 2; Use it: `echo Hello World | grcat red-caps`

Comment: I use `grcat` and really like it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite fond of coloring my prompt so that it stands out. A useful article on that sort of thing is available [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/).

Answer (score 0):

This demo bash script colours directories red in most terminals  - certainly works in xterms and cygwin under Windows. You can adapt the colours by fiddling with the escape codes - Google for LS_COLOR for lists of colour codes:

```
#!/bin/bash

color_red()
{
    echo -e "\033[01;31m$1\033[00m"
}

for FILE in $*
do
    if test -d $FILE
    then
        color_red $FILE
    else
        echo $FILE
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking at logs, you might enjoy `tail -f /var/log/messages | loco` for colorized output.

There's a [screenshot](http://www.zjuul.net/~jules/loco/screenshot.html) at the [loco](http://www.zjuul.net/~jules/loco) website and more examples at http://www.linuxhaxor.net/2008/01/02/perl-script-to-add-nice-colors-to-your-varlogmessages-file

Comment: Both those links are broken for me, can anyone else check?