# Add --color to all Unix commands

Tags: unix, shell

Is it possible to "alias" all commands to append --color? Or instead have it automatically activated for every program that supports it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563500/what-unix-commands-support-coloured-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would the shell know automatically which programs support the --color option? You'd have to give it a list, and as long as you're going to do that you might as well just give it a list of alias commands to run. I suppose it could be done programmatically by something like this (in bash):

```
for cmd in ls blah foo; do
    alias "$cmd=$cmd --color"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be careful with this, especially when chaining invocations.

```
grep --color=yes 'foo' bar.txt | less   #leads to weird ANSI stuff in output
grep --color=yes 'foo' bar.txt | less -R #binary codes interpreted as colors
```

Basically, this can screw up pipelining...I'd recommend aliasing things with colorized output to separate commands to avoid doing "cmd | myprog" and getting weird results due to embedded ANSI.

Comment: Some commands (such as grep) support '--color=auto' which will colorize the output if and only if stdout is a terminal.  If stdout is a pipe, they will not colorize.

Answer (score 1):

There are really very few programs that support the `--color` option, and they aren't actually written by a single organization. Thus, they don't refer to a central location for their options. Heck, the don't even have a uniform argument set, so just the `--color`  option to the end of every command would probably cause a lot of damage!

I'm afraid you'd have to alias each and one. For example, for `ls`:

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of trying to change each command

why not just change the way your console displays colors

Comment: Change the console how? To make it magically display colors for text that the command didn't mark up?